# Why was this character in bacta in Rogue One

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Possible Spoilers ahead.

> *Rogue One* takes place just before *A New Hope* putting it approximately 19 years after the events of *Revenge of the Sith*. **Seeing how it's been nearly two decades since his dismemberment and burning, what's the point of putting Vader in a bacta bath now?** If it would have really helped him regenerate, Palpatine would have had him in one soon after his defeat on Mustafar, but instead immediately took him to surgery and had cybernetics attached. I also don't think it had any pain management purpose because Dark Side users often draw on pain to fuel their Force abilities, so it is unlikely a Sith Lord would try to reduce their own pain.

Comment: I assumed that scene was implying he needs to be immersed in bacta *on a regular basis* to help prevent his injuries from getting any worse than they already are.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Rejuvenation

The container is referred to as a "rejuvenation chamber."

> Vader’s attendant, Vanee, visits Vader as he meditates within a
> rejuvenation chamber.
>
> <sub>*Rogue One: The Ultimate Visual Guide*</sub>

While in Legends this is simply another word for a bacta tank, the word “rejuvenation” suggests to me that Vader is being restored to a usual state: that he is doing damage to his body, and needs to repair it to remain functional. Considering what a wreck he is physically, and the exertion he frequently engages in, it’s not a surprise that he needs frequent treatments even to stay in a workable state.

It is true that, as a Sith Lord, his pain gives him strength:

> Without the neural connection to his armor, he was conscious of the
> stumps of his legs, the ruin of his arms, the perpetual pain in his
> flesh. He welcomed it. Pain fed his hate, and hate fed his strength.
> Once, as a Jedi, he had meditated to find peace. Now he meditated to
> sharpen the edges of his anger.
>
> <sub>*Tarkin*</sub>

However, there must be a balance. Too much pain will disable him, Sith Lord or no, and he must be able to fight and enforce the Emperor’s will.